# React onChange function to LogIn not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I have been on this for 10 hours and It is frustrating to say I have no clue what I am missing.

I am making a simple react app with a **Sign-up and log-in function**,
I have successfully created mypage, and sign up  and here are two things I want to achieve and cannot get it done: 
**1. it should be called handleResponseSuccess callback after log in 

2. it should log in successfully when button click**

even a simple point out will be a huge help.. thank you

***App.js***

```js
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Route, Redirect, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Signup from "./pages/Signup";
import Mypage from "./pages/Mypage";
import axios from "axios";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.staate = {
      isLogin: false,
    userinfo: null,
    }
    this.handleResponseSuccess = this.handleResponseSuccess.bind(this)
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this)
  }

  handleResponseSuccess() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:4000/user')
    .then((res) => {
      this.setState({ isLogin: true, userinfo: { ...res.data }, });
      this.props.history.push("/");
    });
  }

  handler() {
    axios.post('https://localhost:4000/signout', null, {
      withCredentials: true,
    })
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
          isLogin: false,
        });
        this.props.history.push('/')
      })
      .catch((err) => alter(err));
  }


  render() {
    const { isLogin, userinfo } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            path='/login'
            render={() => (
              <Login handleResponseSuccess={this.handleResponseSuccess} />
            )}
          />
          <Route exact path='/signup' render={() => <Signup />} />
          <Route
            exact
            path='/mypage'
            render={() => <Mypage userinfo={userinfo} handleLogout={this.handler}/>}
          />
          <Route
            path='/'
            render={() => {
              if (isLogin) {
                return <Redirect to='/mypage' />;
              }
              return <Redirect to='/login' />;
            }}
          />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default withRouter(App);
```

***login.js***

```js
import React from "react";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      errorMessage: ""
    };
    this.handleInputValue = this.handleInputValue.bind(this);
    this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this)
  }
  handleInputValue = (key) => (e) => {
    this.setState({ [key]: e.target.value });
  };
  handleLogin = () => {
   
    if (this.state.email.length === 0 || this.state.password.length === 0) {
      return this.setState({ errorMessage : "enter email and password"})
    }
    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

    axios.post("https://localhost:4000/signin", {
      email: this.state.email,
      password : this.state.password
    }).then(() => {
      this.props.handleResponseSuccess()
    })
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <center>
          <h1>Sign In</h1>
          <form onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
            <div>
              <span>email</span>
              <input type='email' onChange={this.handleInputValue("email")}></input>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span>password</span>
              <input type='password' onChange={this.handleInputValue("password")}></input>
            </div>
            <div>
              <Link to='/signup'>no id?</Link>
            </div>
            <button className='btn btn-login' type='submit' onClick={this.handleLogin}>
              log in
            </button>
            {this.state.errorMessage ? <div className="alert-box">{this.state.errorMessage}</div> : null}
          </form>
        </center>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Login);
```

Comment: Sounds frustrating! Do you have a working CodeSandbox to demonstrate the error you are running into?

Comment: Your API endpoints are called in a synchronous manner, i.e. your code is treating them as if they happen instantly, but they don't. Add `await` before each of your axios calls, and `async` in those function declarations that use them, i.e. `async () => { ... }`

Comment: @tmdesigned he's chaining his actions within `then` block, which is a valid way to handle promises

Comment: I would add a console.log at `then` block, also chain a `catch` to find if you get any error

Comment: I think @Kevin Yan's answer regarding the typo is the actual problem, but make sure that you render your `App` component inside of a `BrowserRouter` or else the routing won't work.

Comment: @buzatto you are right, I overlooked that she was using `then` callbacks. Forgetting to handle async is just such a common issue here I saw the axios without await and jumped to a conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

in your code in App.js

```
  this.staate = {
      isLogin: false,
    userinfo: null,
    }
```

and you are calling it as

```
   const { isLogin, userinfo } = this.state;
```

maybe this could be of some help